# Make different color of few letters in the middle of the word

Tags: color

I tried to make the following word in Black and Red.

`\textbf{ trans{\textcolor{red}IT}ion'10}`

It gives me the following result -

[image]

But I want both **IT** in red. Why the **T** is not being red.

Comment: `trans\textcolor{red}{IT}ion`

Comment: `\textcolor{red}{IT}`  IT has to be the second argument of the command.

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong input:

```
\textbf{trans\textcolor{red}{IT}ion}
```

or

```
\textbf{trans{\color{red}IT}ion}
```

However, the former is better. Note that `\textcolor` takes two arguments: the color and the text to colorize; to the contrary, `\color` takes only one argument and tells TeX to colorize text from that point on (respecting grouping).

The former is better because you are sure to confine the effect of coloring to the second argument, without worrying about grouping.